# Field not found: 'Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyBootstrapperLocator.Bootstrapper'

Tags: nhibernate, structuremap, nancy

i recently have been using Nancy fx and i'm in love with it, but when i try to make a structuremap ioc like the documentation page suggested i get the error

Field not found: 'Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyBootstrapperLocator.Bootstrapper'.

i have override the getApplicationContainer function like shown in the file

https://github.com/CarlosBolanos/apadrina/blob/master/Application/Bootstrapper.cs

but still get the same error, i look on the code on the rnancy repository
https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.Bootstrappers.StructureMap/blob/master/src/Nancy.Bootstrappers.StructureMap/StructureMapNancyBootstrapper.cs
and i cant see the bootstrapper property

does any1 else have this error too i've been trying to set this up for hours, 
if i remove the nancystructuremap in nugget the error goes away.

or do i need to set something else on the bootstrap class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ran into this scenario after installing `Nancy.Bootstrappers.Ninject` from Nuget.  My Nancy project was created using the Nancy Visual Studio templates, and were referencing Nancy 0.21.1.

What I found was installing the bootstrapper package caused the base Nancy package to get upgraded from 0.21.1 to 0.23.2.  This is fine, except that the `Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet` and the Razor engine packages were NOT upgraded from 0.21.1.

To fix the error, I had to update all of the Nancy-related packages I was using to match the 0.23.2 package.